# mysqli query to fetch row values without loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I am newbie and need help to resolve my issue.

extract row values without loop.

Table:

```
 ----------------
  YEAR  | SALES
 ----------------
 2011  |     45
 2012  |     34
 2013  |     23
 2014  |     10
 2015  |     48
 ----------------
```

PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "YEAR: " . $row["YEAR"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

looking for solution to output the year value without loop , something similar below
while loop prints all row values , but would like to extract individual year value from query and assign it to a variable

```
$year1 = $row["YEAR"]
$year2 = $row["YEAR"]
$year3 = $row["YEAR"]
```

Comment: What about group_concat to concatinate all years in one item?

Comment: What is the issue with using a loop? Have you thought about what you will do next year? Edit your code for having a year added? That is not really the right way to do it...

Comment: You can use `$result->fetch_all()` to get a 2-dimensional array, then use `$year1 = $rows[0]['YEAR']`

Comment: tangled issue,.
$sql = "SELECT DISTINcT  YEAR FROM MyGuests WHERE YEAR = 2014";$result = $conn->query($sql);$year = $result->fetch_raw(),var_dump($year).Maybe you say so ?

Comment: $result->fetch_all() is not working

Comment: You don't want to do that. You want to store your data in a `array` structure.

Comment: That's correct. Any time you find yourself creating a series of numbered variables, they should be in an array.

Comment: @user3855343 `fetch_all` requires the MYSQLND driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your current code

```
       $i=1;
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           ${'year'.$i}= $row["YEAR"];
           $i++;
           //echo "YEAR: " . $row["YEAR"]. "<br>";
          }
```

now you can access $year1; $year2 and so on

Comment: i am glad it helped. and yes others are correct; using array would be more manageable.. but that was not the question i guess..:)